# If $B$ is sequentially compact and $A \subseteq B$ is closed, then $A$ is sequentially compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, proof-verification

$DEF:$ A set $X$ is sequentially compact if $\{x_k\}_{k \geq 1} $ is a sequence and $x_k \in A$ for each $k$, then there is a point $x \in A$ so that $x$ is a limit point of $\{x_k\}_{k \geq 1} $

$PROBLEM$: If $B$ is sequentially compact and $A \subseteq B$ is closed, then $A$ is seq compact.

$ATTEMPT:$ Take a sequence $\{ x_k \} \subseteq A$. Since $A \subseteq B$, then $\{ x_k \} \subseteq B$. But $B$ is seq compact, therefore $\{ x_k \} \to x \in B$, where $x$ is a limit point of $B$. Also, we know $A$ is closed, therefore $A$ must contain all its limit points. since $x_k \in A$ for all $k$ has a limit point $x$, then $x \in A$ so $A$ must be seq compact as required.

Is this correct? Can someone give me some feedback? thanks

Comment: Let $X$ be any sequentially compact but not compact space, and $A = B = X$. Then the premises are met, but $A$ is not compact. Probably, you should show that $A$ is _sequentially_ compact.

Comment: If you convert your erroneous uses of "compact" into "sequentially compact", it will be a correct proof.

Comment: how about now? does it look better?

Comment: You forgot one in the "PROBLEM" line.

Comment: hahahaha ok DONE!

Comment: Wait. The part "therefore $\{x_k\} \to x \in B$, ..." is problematic. What you mean is (if I interpret it right) correct, but not what you wrote. What you want and have is that the sequence has a limit point in $B$ (by sequential compactness of $B$). Any limit point of the sequence lies in $A$ (by closedness of $A$), hence the sequence has a limit point in $A$.

Comment: The definition of sequentially compact is another one: $X$ is called *sequentially compact* if each sequence has a convergent subsequence. On the other hand, $X$ is called *countably compact* if each sequence has a cluster point. Note that a cluster point of $(x_n)_n$ is a point $x$ such that each open $U\ni x$ contains infinitely many $x_n.$ Although it seems likely, this does not imply that a subsequence of $(x_n)_n$ exists which converges to $x.$ However, the statement in your post still holds.